# Element support for Polymer 0.8

Tags: polymer

Is there an ETA to release the core and paper elements for Polymer 0.8?

I noticed that some of the core and paper elements have been refactored for 0.8 in the PolymerLabs git as 0.8-starter-bundle but not sure whether they are ready for dev usage.

I don't want to build with 0.5 and refactor the code in a month for 0.8 or 1.0 beta releases.

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Check out https://github.com/polymerElements. There's also a great dashboard of the porting effort here: http://chuckh.github.io/road-to-polymer/

Comment: Great dashboard to keep track of the migration process! Appreciate your help Eric.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (late April 2015) there is no set dates for releasing `core-` and `paper-` elements for `Polymer 0.8`.

Polymer Team is in the works of building a stable version of `0.8`, which was supposed to have come of by now. On one `mailing-list` some of the Polymer authors mentioned that they will port all the `core-` and `paper-` elements as soon as 0.8 is stable and able to support all of the initial features from `Polymer 0.5.5`.